# How do I find each female names' highest occurence and corresponding state in 1910 from public dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't know how to write the query to find each female names' highest occurence and corresponding state in 1910 from public dataset

For example, I tried for only one name in 1910.

```
select name,state,number high_occurence from `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`  where lower(name)="annie" and year=1910 order by number desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  a.name, 
  a.state, 
  a.year,
  a.number AS high_occurence,
  b.number AS number_in_1910
FROM (
  SELECT 
    name, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(year, state, number) ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`  
  WHERE gender = 'F' 
  GROUP BY name
) a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` b
ON a.name = b.name
AND a.state = b.state
AND b.year = 1910
AND b.gender = 'F'
ORDER BY high_occurence DESC
```

with result as

```sql
Row name        state   year    high_occurence  number_in_1910   
1   Mary        PA      1918    8184            2913     
2   Linda       NY      1947    7542            9    
3   Patricia    NY      1951    5678            33   
4   Helen       PA      1918    5411            1604      
.....    
739 Cele        NY      1914    5               5    
740 Hilja       MI      1910    5               5
```

Comment: very strange downvote :o( - if by chance you read it  - would be great if you can comment on your downvote

Comment: sure, of course it is not you (at least you don't have enough reputation yet for downvotes I think) :o) someone else did  - which might make sense somehow  - soI left comment for that person so he/she might explain why :o)

Comment: @Mikhail, could you please modify the answer to get name,state,high_occurence from the year 1910

Comment: can you please post new question with all specific details, so I (or someone else on SO) will be able to answer :o)